# Is It Possible to do Context/Specification Testing With MSTest?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I'm moderately new to test frameworks and I have been reading up on Moq and [this introductory](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2009/03/13/Beginning-Mocking-With-Moq-3-Part-1.aspx) post used a way of organising tests that I had not seen before.  Further research shows that we in the .Net world tend to meld the terms BDD and Context/Specification (CS) Testing.  I don't want to get into that argument - I am primarily interested in achieving this style of writing test classes.

[This article](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2009/05/27/toward-a-better-use-of-context-specification.aspx) shows the approach again and makes explicit the use of a base class that allows us to construct our specification through the test framework.

This issue I have is that I cannot see an instance method under MSTest that would allow a test fixture to be initialised just once for each test.  The best I can see is the constructor of the test class but that feels a bit wrong.  In NUnit one could use `[TestFixtureSetup]`.  Is there an equivalent using Visual Studio's built in test framework?

**Edit**
I've subsequently moved to NUnit which provides the flexibility I require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation I have moved to using NUnit.  There are several reasons for preferring NUnit over MSTest but, with regards to this particular issue, the compelling reason is that the only class-wide initialisation method supported by MSTest (that doesn't run for every test) is for static methods which is not what I'm looking for.

As Jason points out `[ClassInitialise]` will provide this static, class wide initialisation in MSTest.  There isn't really a way of mimicking the behavior of `[TextFixtureSetup]` found in NUnit such that an instance method is run once before any test in the fixture is run.

Comment: You've made a wise choice sir. Personally, I use NUnit for my testing, since it does seem a lot faster, plus has extra functionality not found in MSTest.

Answer (score 1):

To replicate NUnit's `[TestFixtureSetUp]` for MSTest, try `[ClassInitialize]`. [Here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nnaderi/archive/2007/02/01/mstest-vs-nunit-frameworks.aspx) the link where I found that information. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nnaderi/archive/2007/02/17/explaining-execution-order.aspx) is another useful blog article that might help you.

Comment: Hi Jason, I'm really looking for something I can use in an instance method that will run once for the whole fixture rather than prior to every test in the fixture.  Unfortunately ClassInitialize only applies to static methods.  Thanks for the pointer though.